# How to protect class attributes in Python?

Tags: python, oop

How to protect class from adding attributes in that way:

```
class foo(object):
     pass

x=foo()
x.someRandomAttr=3.14
```

Comment: Use `__slots__ = ()` in class definition. See [`slots`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#slots).

Comment: @falsetru: That is a side-effect, however.

Comment: Do you want an object without **any** attributes? Then just use `x = object()`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - No, I think he is making a class and wants it so that nobody can add anything to it.  In other words, you get _only_ what comes with the class (or namely what he put in it).

Comment: @iCodez: That's why I made that a comment; the question is rather sparse on details.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I think he wants something like `protected` in languages such as Java or C#.

Comment: `protected` attributes would just be unreadable by objects other than  instances of `foo` or `foo` subclasses. It's unrelated to whether or not you can dynamically add attributes to an object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want an immutable object, use the [`collections.namedtuple()` factory](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) to create a class for you:

```
from collections import namedtuple

foo = namedtuple('foo', ('bar', 'baz'))
```

Demo:

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> foo = namedtuple('foo', ('bar', 'baz'))
>>> f = foo(42, 38)
>>> f.someattribute = 42
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'foo' object has no attribute 'someattribute'
>>> f.bar
42
```

Note that the *whole object* is immutable; you cannot change `f.bar` after the fact either:

```
>>> f.bar = 43
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

Answer (score 3):

Override the [`__setattr__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setattr__) method:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
    def __setattr__(self, var, val):
        raise TypeError("You're not allowed to do this")
...     
>>> Foo().x = 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-31-be77d2b3299a>", line 1, in <module>
    Foo().x = 1
  File "<ipython-input-30-cb58a6713335>", line 3, in __setattr__
    raise TypeError("You're not allowed to do this")
TypeError: You're not allowed to do this
```

Even `Foo`'s subclasses will raise the same error:

```
>>> class Bar(Foo):
    pass
... 
>>> Bar().x = 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-35-35cd058c173b>", line 1, in <module>
    Bar().x = 1
  File "<ipython-input-30-cb58a6713335>", line 3, in __setattr__
    raise TypeError("You're not allowed to do this")
TypeError: You're not allowed to do this
```

Comment: This prevents you from setting *any* attributes, including in `__init__()`.

Comment: @chepner -you can still set attrs through the ____dict___. Ugly, but doable.

Comment: @chepner: What @tdelaney meant was you simply need to use `self.__dict__['<attribute-name>'] = <whatever>`. It's a well-know technique used in classes that redefine `__setattr__`.